# Is there any way to have queue members reply to the email to approve an approval request?

Tags: approval-process

I would like all members of a queue to be able to approve a request via replying to the email notification - is this possible? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No that is currently (API 29 - winter 14) not possible and as such [documented in the approval process considerations.](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_considerations.htm&language=en_US) All members of the queue and their delegates will receive an email notification, but they will need to log in to salesforce to do the approval.

> You can't use email approval response with approval processes in which
>   the assigned approver is a queue

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you mean "any" member of the queue. You may find it helpful to create an approver's permission set to assign to all the members of the queue. Most approval processes are looking for the user's manager instead of an "approver", thus the benefit of the permission set. You'll also need to make certain that everyone in the queue is receiving a copy of the email sent to the members of the approver's queue. Your Workflow logic has to be properly set up for it to fire when the first one in the queue gives their approval. Since I don't know how you've determined who's in the queue, there could be any number of ways to do that. So, you'll need to sort the logic out for that yourself. Here are a number of resources you might find of assistance (several are what SF calls "cheatsheets"):

[Security Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_security/workbook_security.pdf)

[Useful Workflow Rules](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_useful_workflow_rules.pdf)

[Getting Started with Approval Processes](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_approvals_cheatsheet.pdf)

[Useful Approval Processes](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_useful_approval_processes.pdf)

[Email Approval FAQ](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_email_approval_faq.pdf)

[Force.com Platform Fundamentals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf)

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question but rather provides some general approval process tips and guidelines.